# CSS elements positioning (1 big element and 5 small)

Tags: css, css-position

Can somebody help me to understand how to make 6 elements look like on the picture (videos part)?

[image: Picture of desired output]

Here's what I have so far:

```css
.videos {
  width: 730px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 5px 15px 0px;
}
.videos > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
#big {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff0e0;
}
#small {
  height: 90px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="videos">
  <header>
    <h2>Videos</h2>
  </header>
  <a href="">Browse all videos</a>
  <br>
  <div id="big">Big video</div>
  <div id="small">Small video</div>
  <div id="small">Small video</div>
  <div id="small">Small video</div>
  <div id="small">Small video</div>
  <div id="small">Small video</div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need to know what you've tried, or at least where you're starting from, to help out. Suggestion: put together a simple example and post it here (create 6 divs with some height and width, then see if you can get the layout you want).  That gives us something to work with, and may help you see what you need to do more easily.

Comment: We are here to help solve problems, not to do your work for you. Could you start with making, for instance, a jsfiddle (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/0bu5w3xx/)), and tell us what parts you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your problem is that widths and heights do not include the sizes of the margins. So if you have, say, a 6 pixel margin between everything, and the bigger rectangle is 200px high, the smaller rectangles need to be 97px high to make everything line up.

Then there's the problem of spaces: with inline-blocks, newlines in the source take up a space horizontally, which throw things out of alignment. I changed the inline-blocks to floats.

And you can't have duplicate ids in a HTML document. I needed to change the ids to classes.
(This doesn't really matter for CSS, but it would be a big problem in other cases, so it's best to play it safe and not have errors.)

You also missed a `/` in the source; the second `<h2>` should have been `</h2>`.

That's about it.

```css
.videos {
  width: 630px;
  height:400px;
  margin: 15px 5px 15px 0px;
}
.videos > div {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 6px 6px 0;
  background-color: #fff0e0;
}

.big {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}
.small {
  height: 97px;
  width: 197px;
}
```

```html
<div class="videos">
  <header>
    <h2>Videos</h2>
  </header>
  <a href="">Browse all videos</a>
  <br>
  <div class="big">Big video</div>
  <div class="small">Small video</div>
  <div class="small">Small video</div>
  <div class="small">Small video</div>
  <div class="small">Small video</div>
  <div class="small">Small video</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="left-wrapper-lg">

    <div class="big-col">
    </div>

    <div class="small-col">
    </div>

    <div class="small-col no-margin">
    </div>

</div>

<div id="left-wrapper-sm">

    <div class="full-col">
    </div>

    <div class="full-col">
    </div>

    <div class="full-col">
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left-wrapper-lg {
    float:left;
    width:64%;
    margin-right:2%;    
}

#left-wrapper-sm {
    float:left;
    width:34%;
    margin-right:0;
}

.no-margin { margin:0 !important;}

.big-col {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin-right:0%;
}

.small-col {
    float:left;
    width:48%;
    margin-right:2;
}

.full-col {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css , [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr1gmda1/)

```
   .videos {
    width: 730px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 5px 15px 0px;
}

.videos > div {
    display: inline-block; 
}

#big {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #fff0e0; 
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
}

#small {
    height: 90px;
    width: 195px;
    background-color: #fff0e0;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
}
```